# Retrieve iPhone Battery State of Health

Tags: c#, ios, .net

Is there any possible way I can retrieve the State Of Health of my iPhone's Battery using C# ?

I have a project where I have to retrieve the SOH and it just so happens that the language I am most familiar with is C#

I know this is possible via Swift, XCode or iOS Environment but I/we are currently running under the .Net framework right now.

I have done several other things including retrieving the phone's `imei` or part number or serial number via mobiledevice.dll and/or Manzana Library but now my goal is to get the Battery's SOH

Hoping for a favorable response. thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. please have a look this source code from `libimobiledevice`
https://github.com/libimobiledevice-win32/libimobiledevice

if you don't want to compile yourself, you can download already compile binary from here. http://docs.quamotion.mobi/en/latest/imobiledevice/download.html

They have nuget package as well. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/imobiledevice-net/

using `cmd` , `idevicediagnostics diagnostics`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>GasGauge</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CycleCount</key>
        <integer>101</integer>
        <key>DesignCapacity</key>
        <integer>1600</integer>
        <key>FullChargeCapacity</key>
        <integer>1600</integer>
        <key>Status</key>
        <string>Success</string>
    </dict>
    <key>HDMI</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Connection</key>
        <string>Unplugged</string>
        <key>Status</key>
        <string>Success</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NAND</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Status</key>
        <string>NANDInfoFailed</string>
    </dict>
    <key>WiFi</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Active</key>
        <string>YES</string>
        <key>Status</key>
        <string>Success</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```